# centering the div inside the div automatically

Tags: html, css

I have this jsFiddle: [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/06b56fe9/)

```
<div class="image-info">
        <img id="cart-image" src="http://www.wonderoftech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/BlackBerry-Q10-Sample-3-300x300.jpg">
        <div class="pizza-hint">sample text</div>
</div>
```

So in the fiddle above you can see that when you **hover on the div** the sample text is not actually center horizontally I tried margin auto but it didnt work.

My question is that how can I center it automatically when text length is increasing?

Comment: Margin auto won't work with position: absolute. You probably need to wrap your tooltip inside an extra container div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/06b56fe9/1/)

Added stuff:

```
.image-info {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; <-added
    font-size: 0;          <-added
}

div:HOVER .pizza-hint {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;                                  <- changed
    left: 50%;                                 <- changed
    border: 1px solid white;                   
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);       <- added
     -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);  <- added
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);           <- added
    margin-left: 0;                            <- changed
    margin-right: 0;                           <- changed
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(227, 255, 255, 0.7);
    background: rgba(227, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A Cross browser solution,

Use Image as background image of `image-info` div. And use below css,

**HTML :**

```
<div class="image-info" style="background-image:url(http://www.wonderoftech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/BlackBerry-Q10-Sample-3-300x300.jpg);">
    <div class="pizza-hint">sample text</div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.image-info {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:blue;
}
.image-info:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em;
}

.pizza-hint {
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    display: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(227, 255, 255, 0.7);
    background: rgba(227, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

div:HOVER .pizza-hint {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML, CSS **[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/06b56fe9/3/)**